# Не понимаю свойство транзакции: согласованность

Tags: mysql, sql

Ребят, заранее благодарю за помощь:-)
В общем, не могу понять свойство транзакции, которое называется свойством согласованности. Как я понял, это знач...да нифига я не понял)) Буду очень благодарен, если вы объясните с примером из жизни, допустим с примером счетов клиентов в банке или тому подобному.

Comment: Ну вроде в википедии есть как раз пример из жизни как раз про счета в банке https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID#Consistency_%E2%80%94_%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C